# How to update a second listbox items upon selecting an item to the first listbox without creating a button? Windows Powershell Forms

Tags: powershell, active-directory

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2gD1z.png)

So when i select lists from there it automatically refresh the value of the second listbox. But my problem is the update only occurs when i close the form and re-opens it.

do{
if($OuRegionsListBox.SelectedIndices.Count -ge 1 ){
Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -LDAPFilter '(name=*)' -SearchBase $OURegionItem -SearchScope OneLevel | foreach{[void]$PropertyOuListBox.Items.Add($_.name)}
}
}while($OuRegionsListBox.SelectedIndicesCount -le 0 )

My code does is, it adds the items to the 2nd listbox (PropertyOUlistbox) when you select an OU in the first listbox (OuRegionslistbox).

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JAqg8.png)